# ¿Es posible obtener número de índices sin bucle?

Tags: javascript, regex

Estoy intentando hacer un programa que me devuelva no solo el índice de la primera coincidencia de una expresión regular, si no de todas las coincidencias, eso si, sin poder utilizar un bucle.
He estado buscando y no lo he sabido encontrar, he probado varias maneras, incluso utilizando modificadores como la `g` y he llegado a pensar que no es posible.....

Alguien me puede ayudar, es posible?

Gracias de ante mano

Saludos.

```js
function buscar() {

  let palabra = document.getElementById("texto").value;
  let letra = document.getElementById("letra").value;
  let re = new RegExp(letra, "gi")

  console.log(palabra.search(re))
}
```

```html
Texto: <input type="text" id="texto" /><br> 
Letra: <input type="text" id="letra" /><br>
<button onclick="buscar()">Buscar</button>
```

Dado el texto siguiente:

```
texto = "hola como va todo"
texto.search(/o/gi);
```

En este ejemplo, si buscamos la letra `o`, espero que devuelva el índice de todas las `o` que estén el el texto, no solo de la primera `o` que encuentra.

Ejemplo:

```
índices =[1, 6, 8, 14, 16]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para obtener el índice de todas las ocurrencias podes utilizar [`string.matchAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll)

> El método matchAll() retorna un iterador de todos los resultados de ocurrencia en una cadena de texto contra una expresión regular, incluyendo grupos de captura.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
function buscar() {

  let palabra = document.getElementById("texto").value;
  let letra = document.getElementById("letra").value;
  let re = new RegExp(letra, "gi")
  let matches = Array.from(palabra.matchAll(re), m => m.index);

  console.log(matches);
}
```

```html
Texto: <input type="text" id="texto" value="asdasd" /><br> 
Letra: <input type="text" id="letra" value="a" /><br>
<button onclick="buscar()">Buscar</button>
```

---

**PD1**: [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) puede ser considerado un *"bucle"* ya que recorre todos los elementos del iterable.
**PD2**: Gracias [@Alfredo Maussa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/170764/alfredo-maussa) por tu sugerencia.

Comment: Parece que también se puede escribir como:
`let matches = Array.from(palabra.matchAll(re), m => m.index);`
[String.prototype.matchAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll)

Comment: @AlfredoMaussa, actualice mi respuesta. Gracias por tu comentario!

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Marcos, simplemente no conocía este método, utilicé match, pero solo me devolvía la primera coincidencia y no su índice, si no, la expresión en sí.

Answer (score 2):

Siempre va a hacer un bucle aunque parezca que no lo hace, ya te han dado buenas soluciones, solo quiero agregar que siempre se puede "abusar" de la función `.replace`, porque se le puede pasar como argumento un callback:

```js
const texto = "hola como va todo";

const resultado = [];

texto.replace(/(o)/gi, (m, g, i) => resultado.push(i));

console.log(resultado);
```

En este caso "m" es el match, la "g" el grupo de captura e "i" el index de cada match.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Emeeus, No conocía esta sintaxis de replace, donde te devuelve esos parámetros. A partir de aquí, decidiré cual de las tres buena respuestas que me habéis dado incluiré en el código, gracias ¡¡¡

Answer (score 0):

Parece que el problema es no usar el método correcto. En python con el cual soy más familiar sería `.findall` (devuelve un array) y no `.search` (devuelve solo el primer valor).

Buscando en esta [Guía de Mozilla: Expresiones Regulares](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) puedes encontrar el valor que devuelve:

**Search** [[ir](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search#valor_devuelto)]
El índice de la primera coincidencia entre la expresión regular y la cadena de texto proporcionada, si no se encuentra devuelve -1.

**Match** [[ir](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#resumen)]
El método match() se usa para obtener todas las ocurrencias de una expresión regular dentro de una cadena.

**MatchAll** [[ir](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll)]
El método matchAll() retorna un iterador de todos los resultados de ocurrencia en una cadena de texto contra una expresión regular, incluyendo grupos de captura.

**La que coincide con lo que deseas es `.match` y no `.search`**

```js
function buscar() {

  let palabra = document.getElementById("texto").value;
  let letra = document.getElementById("letra").value;
  let re = new RegExp(letra, "gi")

  console.log(palabra.match(re))
}
```

```html
Texto: <input type="text" id="texto" /><br> 
Letra: <input type="text" id="letra" /><br>
<button onclick="buscar()">Buscar</button>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, Alfredo Maussa, con el método match, ya lo probé, pero me devolvía la expresión en sí, no su índice, claro no supe trabajar con el.